# How to launch bugzilla after installation?

Tags: 11.04, software-center

I have installed Bugzilla 3 through the software center.

After a successful result, what is the next step?

I can't see an installation directory anywhere.

I tried:

```
http://localhost/bugzilla
```

There is nothing there.

Adding information:

- I installed it from the software center. I am not aware to prerequisites.

  [image]
- Should I install perl modules? how please?
- Apache2 - installed and running before the installation
- Mysql is installed

  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
- Perl -v

  This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi
  (with 53 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

What should I do now?

Comment: Thanks Rinzqind. Your suggestions are great, however, I think the problem lies on the installation itself. If I use the software center, indeed that takes me closer to a Windows OS isntallation, but if I need to add/edit/modify or missing prereq - software - that is not mentioned anywhere.  I have read some step by step guildes, and I will follow your advice, but I do not understand why a dual installation (gui/command line) is needed here.

Comment: If you get it working add it in here as an answer and approve it. I  shall remove comments when you do ;) BTW! I used the DOWNLOAD not the repo; I saw claims that the repo version  needs some more love and care to be good...

Comment: @Rinzwind I get many error on the Perl part Your #5. I will start a new question for them for now

Comment: Answer is located here http://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla

Comment: What I meant is post it below this one as an answer and accept it! Otherwise the system will keep this open ;-)

Comment: I got more than enough rep ;)

Comment: ok, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is located here http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla

Answer (score 1):

You were so close to making it work :) the URL to visit after the installation is http://localhost/bugzilla3 :)

I tried it on a virtualbox instance and it does work flawlessly.

All the dependencies are installed automatically along with bugzilla (apache, mysql, perl modules) - as always happening when you use apt-get/synaptic/Software Center, that's the whole point of package management.

Post-install scripts create databases, it asks you for passwords for Mysql's root user and for bugzilla user. Even Apache is restarted with new configuration.

Absolutely no need to install everything manually, unless you're an experienced admin and have very specific requirements.

Comment: I changed the folder from bugzilla3 to bugzilla