# How do I install Bugzilla?

Tags: software-installation, bugzilla

I would like to use Bugzilla on my own computer to track and trace bugs in our own software. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For Bugzilla you need...

- Perl (5.8.1 or above)
- MySQL
- Apache2
- Bugzilla
- Perl modules
- Bugzilla using apache

Some remarks up front:

If any of these are already installed just keep an eye on settings that need to be set. Check these with what you used and change them to your needs.

If you need information about Perl, MySQL, Apache these are some LAMP how tos: [1](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/ubuntu-11.04-natty), [2](http://www.multimediaboom.com/how-to-install-lamp-server-in-ubuntu-11-0410-1010-04/), [3](http://all-about-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/05/lamplinux-apache-mysql-php-with-ubuntu.html), [4](http://gregrickaby.com/2011/05/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu-1104-natty.html), [5](http://www.bugzilla.org/).

Also have a look at [this how to](http://neil.motorcyclemarket.com/how-to-install-bugzilla-4-0-step-by-step-tutorial-that-works) (from Saariko in comment) if the below does not work for you.

<sub>If anyone finds typos feel free to fix them, or if you can think of improvements feel free to add them in</sub>

Here we go...

1. **Perl**

   Verify what perl you are using:

   ```
   perl -v
   ```

   It should show something like this:

   ```
   This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi
   (with 53 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
   ```

   Natty uses 5.10. If yours is lower than 5.8.1 you need to upgrade it.
2. **MySQL**

   Verify if you have a MySQL running with

   ```
   mysql --version
   ```

   If not installed install [mysql-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mysql-server) [image: Install mysql-server][mysql-admin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mysql-admin) [image: Install mysql-admin][mysql-client](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mysql-client)

   Make sure to follow guidelines and set up a `root` account with a decent password. See the links above for how to set up a LAMP server if you need it.
   Create a user `bugzilla` (change it if you want something else)

   ```
   sudo useradd -d /home/bugzilla -m bugzilla
   sudo passwd bugzilla
   ```

   And create a database and set permissions for user `bugzilla`

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   mysql> create database bugzilla;
   mysql> grant all privileges on bugzilla.* to bugzilla@localhost;
   ```

   You need database name, user name and password for the user later on.
3. **Apache**

   Verify if Apache is installed:

   ```
   apache2 -v
   ```

   and

   ```
   http://localhost
   ```

   should show a welcome page or a website. 
   If not installed...install [apache2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apache2) [image: Install apache2]
   Configure apache2 as you normally would. See the links at the top for how to set up a LAMP server if you need more.

   And now for the important part... setting up bugzilla in apache2:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

   and edit in the following ...

   ```
   Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/bugzilla/
   <directory /var/www/bugzilla>
   Addhandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
   Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
   DirectoryIndex index.cgi
   AllowOverride Limit
   </directory>
   ```

   (Note the trailing "/" on the first line)

   Add a user `apache2` if you do not have this already.

   ```
    sudo useradd -d /home/apache2 -m apache2
    sudo passwd apache2
   ```

   Add the user to apache2 variables...

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/envvars
   ```

   and include

   ```
    export APACHE_RUN_USER=apache2
    export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=apache2
   ```

   The `cgi` addhandler could be in another place if you install bugzilla from the repositories (see [apache cgi how to](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html))
4. **Bugzilla**

   Install [bugzilla3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bugzilla3) [image: Install bugzilla3]

   Or download the latest stable (4.0.2 at the moment) or latest cutting edge version from  [bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/). Short instruction on the latter:

   ```
    sudo tar -xvf bugzilla-4.0.2.tar
    sudo mv /download/bugzilla-4.0.2 /usr/local/
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/bugzilla-4.0.2 /var/www/bugzilla
   ```

   Make sure the directory has rw permissions:

   ```
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/bugzilla
   ```
5. **Perl modules for Bugzilla**

   Bugzilla uses a script `checksetup.pl` to check if everything is set up correctly and if things changed to set them up for you. By manually installing the perl modules you can skip this.

   Check if all modules are installed:

   ```
    cd /var/www/bugzilla/
    sudo ./checksetup.pl --check-modules
   ```

   If not installed...

   ```
    sudo perl -MCPAN -e install
   ```

   `localconfig` holds the configurations and needs to be set up. So...

   ```
    sudo -H gedit localconfig
   ```

   and change $db_name to the database name, #db_user to the user and $db_password to the password you used during setup of MySQL.

   ```
    $db_name = 'bugzilla';
    $db_user = 'bugzilla';
    $db_pass = 'bugzilla@pwpspaswsword';
   ```

   After saving these settings

   ```
   cd /var/www/bugzilla/
   sudo ./checksetup.pl
   ```

   will add all kinds of tables to MySQL.
   Adding server group `apache2` to bugzilla:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /var/www/bugzilla/localconfig
   ```

   and add

   ```
   $webservergroup = 'apache2';
   ```

   To include these changes do a

   ```
   cd /var/www/bugzilla/
   sudo ./checksetup.pl
   ```

   and this will ask you to setup your administrator for bugzilla.
6. **It works!!**

   Restart apache2

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

   and open a browser and insert URL

   ```
   http://localhost/bugzilla/
   ```

   and I have a working bugzilla login page on my own machine.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed your AllowOveride Limit to AllowOveride All, just a little note to all like me :) Other than that, you wrote a great guide....

Comment: I have followed your advices on Quantal Ubuntu. `sudo ./checksetup.pl` reported no errors. But when I open the`http//<servername>/bugzilla3` I see listing of content of the /var/www/bugzilla dir, not the bugzilla itself. Can you help me? (BTW, access to any file in /var/www/bugzilla is denied if accessed by the Firefox; maybe this is a problem).

Answer (score 14):

I think a much shorter answer would be much more helpful:

```
sudo apt-get install bugzilla3
```

it asks a few questions. Then just open your browser and go to http://localhost/bugzilla3

All dependencies are installed automatically, everything is configured automatically. Automatic install should work in most cases, even if Apache or Mysql are already installed and configured (unless some non-trivial changes in their configuration have been made)

Novice Ubuntu users are misled by the detailed build-it-from-tarballs instructions.

Comment: I want to point a great [guide](http://neil.motorcyclemarket.com/how-to-install-bugzilla-4-0-step-by-step-tutorial-that-works) that I found on a step by step install.

Comment: You should've specified that you need Bugzilla 4. Installing bugzilla 3 is a one-step process, even in the guide you linked to.

Comment: I tried it with bugzilla 3 and it did not only **not** install all perl modules for me it did also **not** adjust apache2 for me. The above setup worked for me (but I started with a working apache2 (and in a VM ( ;) )) so perl and php set up to work).

Comment: oh nice guide @Saariko :)

Comment: On a clean Ubuntu installation you can also just use Synaptic Package Manager. Tree clicks, and you're all set-up to go.

Comment: @Saariko dead link

Comment: Dead link snapshot from 2013 https://web.archive.org/web/20130320102715/http://neil.motorcyclemarket.com/how-to-install-bugzilla-4-0-step-by-step-tutorial-that-works

Comment: "Unable to locate package bugzilla3".  It does not say in which repository it goes.  So not helpful.