# Error when install perl modules for bugzilla 4.0,2

Tags: 11.04, bugzilla

Following instructions on [How do I install Bugzilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/can-i-use-my-own-version-of-bugzilla)
I am getting Perl errors when trying to install the missing modules.

The script:

```
cd /var/www/bugzilla/
sudo ./checksetup.pl --check-modules
```

Returns tons of errors among:

```
* This is Bugzilla 4.0.2 on perl 5.10.1
* Running on Linux 2.6.32-33-generic-pae #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 22:06:29 UTC 2011

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.55 
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.47 
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.21)     ok: found v2.23 
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     not found 
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.71)     not found 
Checking for                  DBI (v1.41)     ok: found v1.609 
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     found v2.20 
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.00)     ok: found v2.198 
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    found v1.903 
Checking for                  URI (any)       ok: found v1.52 
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.22)     not found 

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v1.45)     not found 
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.00)     ok: found v4.012 
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found 

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.39 
Checking for                Chart (v2.1)      ok: found v2.4.1 
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       ok: found v1.56 
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       ok: found v0.86 
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       ok: found v1.44 
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    not found 
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v5.834 
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       ok: found v3.32 
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.4)    not found 
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       not found 
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       not found 
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       not found 
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    not found 
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       not found 
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      not found 
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       not found 
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.40)     ok: found v3.64 
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       not found 
Checking for Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper (any)       not found 
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       not found 
Checking for          TheSchwartz (any)       not found 
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       not found 
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) not found 
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.93)     not found 
Checking for   Math-Random-Secure (v0.05)     not found 
WARNING: We could not check the configuration of Apache. This sometimes
happens when you are not running checksetup.pl as root. To see the
problem we ran into, run: /usr/sbin/apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES

***********************************************************************
* REQUIRED MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Bugzilla requires you to install some Perl modules which are either *
* missing from your system, or the version on your system is too old. *
* See below for commands to install these modules.                    *
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*                    MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                 *
***********************************************************************
*                     MIME-tools * Move Bugs Between Installations    *
*                    PatchReader * Patch Viewer                       *
*                      perl-ldap * LDAP Authentication                *
*                    Authen-SASL * SMTP Authentication                *
*                     RadiusPerl * RADIUS Authentication              *
*                      SOAP-Lite * XML-RPC Interface                  *
*                       JSON-RPC * JSON-RPC Interface                 *
*                        JSON-XS * Make JSON-RPC Faster               *
*                     Test-Taint * JSON-RPC Interface, XML-RPC Interface *
*                  HTML-Scrubber * More HTML in Product/Group Descriptions *
* Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper * Inbound Email                      *
*                    Email-Reply * Inbound Email                      *
*                    TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                      *
*                 Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                      *
*                       mod_perl * mod_perl                           *
*               Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                           *
*             Math-Random-Secure * Improve cookie and token security  *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

     MIME-tools: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl MIME::Parser
    PatchReader: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl PatchReader
      perl-ldap: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Net::LDAP
    Authen-SASL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Authen::SASL
     RadiusPerl: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Authen::Radius
      SOAP-Lite: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl SOAP::Lite
       JSON-RPC: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl JSON::RPC
        JSON-XS: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl JSON::XS
     Test-Taint: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Test::Taint
  HTML-Scrubber: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl HTML::Scrubber
Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper
    Email-Reply: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::Reply
    TheSchwartz: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl TheSchwartz
 Daemon-Generic: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Daemon::Generic
       mod_perl: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl mod_perl2
Apache-SizeLimit: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Apache2::SizeLimit
Math-Random-Secure: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Math::Random::Secure

COMMANDS TO INSTALL REQUIRED MODULES (You *must* run all these commands
and then re-run this script):

    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime::TimeZone
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::MIME
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl List::MoreUtils

To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all

*** Installation aborted. Read the messages above. ***
```

Running the suggested command:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
```

isn't changing much

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/compile.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 2 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  1-2
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/memory.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/range.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 16 tests but ran 0.
t/seed.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 8 tests but ran 0.
Files=7, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.01 sys +  0.11 cusr  0.06 csys =  0.21 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 4/7 test programs. 2/2 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  MKANAT/Math-Random-Secure-0.06.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MKANAT/Math-Random-Secure-0.06.tar.gz
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I found missing was: `sudo cpan App::cpanminus` - Once that was installed, most errors have dissappeared.

Only errors left are for optional modules.