# Bugzilla is not running - Access forbidden

Tags: localhost, bugzilla

I have install Bugzilla according to [How do I install Bugzilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla)

I can't access the files. apparently /usr/local/

```
drwxr-xr-- 16 www-data www-data 4096 2011-09-19 09:30 bugzilla-4.0.2/
```

The link from /var/www/

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   25 2011-09-18 13:53 bugzilla -> /usr/local/bugzilla-4.0.2/
```

When browsing to: http://localhost/bugzilla I get :

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /bugzilla on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.22 Port 80

How to fix it please?

Comment: I added this to my apache2.conf file
Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/bugzilla
<directory /var/www/bugzilla>
Addhandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit
</directory>

Comment: Oh, and the apache error_log file might well tell you more about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the link to work, www-data will have to have the following permissions:

> **rx** on /usr, /usr/local, /usr/local/bugzilla and any sub-folder
>
> **r** on any files within /usr/local/bugzilla

Oh, and the apache error_log file might well tell you more about the problem.

Comment: Do I really need X on /usr? why is the link than? This exposes all of my subfolders for execute permission. Isn't it too much?

Comment: To follow a symlink a user needs to be able to navigate to the folder in question, so needs X all the way. If you don't like this then you could use mount (-o bind, from memory) to mount your folder on top of /var/www/bugzilla.