# How to solve this error: There is no perl module on CPAN named [modulename]

Tags: perl, bugzilla, cpan

I am trying to install bugzilla optional modules, but get this error:

[image]

I tried using

```
cpan Module::mod_perl2
```

but with no success as well.

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to install mod_perl2 from Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
```

If you're not happy with this, see [mod_perl2 documentation](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/install/install.html) - I don't see where it suggests the syntax you're using.

**UPDATE:** You're doing it all wrong. :) See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla/62227#62227)

Comment: Thanks, after removing all mysql dbs, and other bugzillas' I followed a [very good step by step guide](http://neil.motorcyclemarket.com/how-to-install-bugzilla-4-0-step-by-step-tutorial-that-works) only one thing left. i will make a question.