# Internal Server Error 500 Bugzilla installation

Tags: debian, bugzilla, cgi

I followed this tutorial in [installing Bugzilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla), I didn't encounter any problem not until I hit localhost/bugzilla in the URL. My `sites-available/default` config is as follows:

```
    #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/bugzilla/
    <Directory /var/www/bugzilla>
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
            Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.cgi
            AllowOverride Limit
    </Directory>
    #<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    #       AllowOverride All
    #       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    #       Order allow,deny
    #       Allow from all
    #</Directory>
```

And when tailing at `var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi' failed
```

---

From comments ...

```
ls -l -rwxr-x--- 1 root apache2 2.6K Feb 20 01:16 /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi
```

Comment: What do you mean by show us at least the result of `/var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi`. How do I know `acl or SELinux?

Comment: Oh, I get this `-rwxr-x--- 1 root apache2 2.6K Feb 20 01:16 /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi`

Comment: im confused too, so I'll do a `chown -R www-data apache2`?

Comment: I believe yes, I have. Because on my apache2.conf it says User www-data & Group www-data (Debian Squeeze)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a

```
ls -l /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi
```

and it shows

```
ls -l -rwxr-x--- 1 root apache2 2.6K Feb 20 01:16 /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi
```

you will see that the user of the file (`root`) is not the apache user. Change it to the user you use for Apache. Let's assume this is `www-data` then ...

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi
```

will change this file (and only this file) to user `www-data`. This will set all files in `/var/www/bugzilla/` to user www-data:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/bugzilla/
```

Be careful with that one though: it might change more than you want.

Comment: Why not `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/bugzilla/`?

Comment: If you want that I'll add that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `$webservergroup`, and `$use_suexec` set correctly for your setup in Bugzilla's `localconfig` file, then run `checksetup.pl` and it will take care of fixing all of your permissions.  If you have root access on the box (which it looks like you do since you can mess with the apache config) then `$use_suexec` should be 0 and `$webservergroup` should be "`www-data`".  Make sure you are root when you run `checksetup.pl`.