# Problems in installing bugzilla on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: users, phpmyadmin, bugzilla

I'm trying to install Bugzilla.

I have `Phpmyadmin` installed in my system so I can't follow the [instructions](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/quick-start.html) on the Bugzilla site that tells me to remove the `/var/www/html` folder because I have `Phpmyadmin` in there.

Besides I have seen the instructions here on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla), but I don't want to create other users on my machine and I want to install Bugzilla for my default user because I'm the only one who uses this machine.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
sudo su
apt-get install git nano
apt-get install apache2 mysql-server libappconfig-perl libdate-calc-perl libtemplate-perl libmime-perl build-essential libdatetime-timezone-perl libdatetime-perl libemail-sender-perl libemail-mime-perl libemail-mime-modifier-perl libdbi-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libcgi-pm-perl libmath-random-isaac-perl libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-perl2 libapache2-mod-perl2-dev libchart-perl libxml-perl libxml-twig-perl perlmagick libgd-graph-perl libtemplate-plugin-gd-perl libsoap-lite-perl libhtml-scrubber-perl libjson-rpc-perl libdaemon-generic-perl libtheschwartz-perl libtest-taint-perl libauthen-radius-perl libfile-slurp-perl libencode-detect-perl libmodule-build-perl libnet-ldap-perl libauthen-sasl-perl libtemplate-perl-doc libfile-mimeinfo-perl libhtml-formattext-withlinks-perl libgd-dev lynx-cur python-sphinx
cd /var/www/html
git clone --branch release-5.0-stable https://git.mozilla.org/bugzilla/bugzilla bugzilla
cd bugzilla
gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
```

Altered on Line 52: `max_allowed_packet=100M`

Added as new line 31, in the `[mysqld]` section: `ft_min_word_len=2`

```
mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bugs.* TO bugs@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$my_pass'"
service mysql restart
gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla.conf`
```

Added:

```
ServerName localhost
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
  AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options
</Directory>
```

Then:

```
a2ensite bugzilla
a2enmod cgi headers expires
service apache2 restart
cd /var/www/html/bugzilla
./checksetup.pl
```

It gave me some errors so I run:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl –all
./checksetup.pl
gedit localconfig
```

Line 29: set `$webservergroup` to `www-data`

Line 67: set `$db_pass` to the password for the bugs user I have created in MySQL a few steps ago

```
./checksetup.pl (again)
./testserver.pl http://localhost/
```

And then I get this error:

```
strictures.pm extra testing active but couldn't load all modules. Missing were:

  indirect multidimensional bareword::filehandles

Extra testing is auto-enabled in checkouts only, so if you're the author
of a strictures-using module you need to run:

  cpan indirect multidimensional bareword::filehandles

but these modules are not required by your users.
TEST-OK Webserver is running under group id in $webservergroup.
TEST-FAILED Fetch of images/padlock.png failed
Your web server could not fetch http://localhost/images/padlock.png.
Check your web server configuration and try again.
```

So what did I do wrong?

As you can see I'd like to install Bugzilla `/var/www/html/` folder where I have also `Phpmyadmin` so I will have: `/var/www/html/bugzilla`.

Thanks.

**Edit**: after running: `cpan indirect multidimensional bareword::filehandles` the problem is still:

```
TEST-OK Webserver is running under group id in $webservergroup.
TEST-FAILED Fetch of images/padlock.png failed
Your web server could not fetch http://localhost/images/padlock.png.
Check your web server configuration and try again.
```

**Edit 2**:

Ok, the only thing I found in `apache2` logs is `/var/log/other_vhosts_access.log`:

```
localhost:80 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2015:10:29:06 +0200] "GET /images/padlock.png HTTP/1.1" 404 469 "-" "libwww-perl/6.05"
```

and `/var/log/error.log`:

```
[Mon Jul 27 10:14:38.112755 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7477] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 10:14:38.112794 2015] [core:notice] [pid 7477] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Did you run `cpan indirect multidimensional bareword::filehandles` ?

Comment: Ok I did right now and the only problem that I still have is: `TEST-OK Webserver is running under group id in $webservergroup.
TEST-FAILED Fetch of images/padlock.png failed
Your web server could not fetch http://localhost/images/padlock.png.
Check your web server configuration and try again.`

Comment: Check the apache2 log in /var/log/ for notices. (the problem is a config problem so not really something we can answer). Likely /var/log/apache2/error* is going to tell what. Oh could be a domain issue too.

Comment: Ok, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.7, bugzilla 5.0. Also wants to set as http://localhost/bugzilla.

The trick was to think... Yes, simply.

You executed:

```
./testserver.pl http://localhost
```

when in fact you should have used

```
./testserver.pl http://localhost/bugzilla
```

since it needs as input the location of itself (yeah, pretty dumb).

Comment: You are missing a "g".

Answer (score 0):

For me (Linux Mint 17.2; Bugzilla 5.0.1, Apache 2.4.7) this helped (finally, after trying a lot of other things):

Changed `AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options` to `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. The problem for me was related to the `AllowOverride` setting as well. This is in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and was set to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <"Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecDGI +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride Limit
    Order Allow,deny
    Allow from all
  <Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

The line `AllowOverride` was changed to read:

```
AllowOverride None
```

The file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bugzilla.conf` has the following Directory entry:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirecortryIndex index.cgi index.html
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

That fixed the issue for me.