# installing bugzilla on 16.04 Server : TEST-WARNING Failed to find the GID for the 'httpd' process

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, bugzilla

I am trying to install bugzilla on my home server running 16.04. I am using the [documentation](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/quick-start.html) and I got up the the 2nd checksetup phase, but am having an issue in step 3.1.11. Test Server.

When running the testserver.pl script I get the following error:

```
$ sudo perl testserver.pl http://localhost/bugzilla
TEST-WARNING Failed to find the GID for the 'httpd' process, unable
to validate webservergroup.
TEST-FAILED Fetch of images/padlock.png failed
Your web server could not fetch http://localhost/bugzilla/images/padlock.png.
Check your web server configuration and try again.
```

Googling around, I found a couple of links, beginning with [this one.](http://support-bugzilla.mozilla.narkive.com/WHKLFinD/test-server-pl-failed-to-find-the-gid-for-the-httpd-process) That link instructs to look at a couple of lines in the testserver.pl script:

```
my @pscmds = ('ps -eo comm,gid', 'ps -acxo command,gid', 'ps -acxo command,rgid');
```

and

```
if ($line =~ /^(?:\S*\/)?(?:httpd|apache)2?\s+(\d+)$/) {
```

It says to run each of the ps commands manually in the shell and look at the output. Sure enough, httpd|apache does not return anything. Somewhere on that page there is some discussion of a truncated name:

```
It looks to me like it's the truncation of the names that is causing the
problem? Note it's '/usr/sbin/apach' which is returned
I also note that /usr/sbin/apach sometimes gets a GID of 33 sometimes of 0
```

my ps output also shows `/usr/sbin/apach`, but I did not see any instructions as to what change to make.

The other link I found was an [askubuntu question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653219/problems-in-installing-bugzilla-on-ubuntu-15-04)  That link seemed mainly concerned with the "AllowOverride" value, which I believe in my case is correct. As per the instructions, I created a file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla.conf` :

```
ServerName localhost

<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

in my local config, for webserver group I have:
    $webservergroup = 'www-data';

One other thing that may or may not be a factor; one of the perl packages was not found during the installation.

```
E: Package 'apache2-mpm-prefork' has no installation candidate
```

Thanks for any help.

*Some additional resources*
[Bug 380732](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380732)

**Update**
I resolved this issue by removing/purging apache2 and re-installing. All was good after that.