# bugzilla is not running as expected

Tags: 11.04, bugzilla

After an isntallation of bugzilla, and after several answers answered
[Bugzilla is not running - Access forbidden](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62058/bugzilla-is-not-running-access-forbidden)
[How do I install Bugzilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla)
[How to launch bugzilla after installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61928/how-to-launch-bugzilla-after-installation)

When I go to the http://localhost/bubzilla I do not get the bugzilla application, but rather a list of files (directory browsing)
[image]

What am I missing please?

ADD

I want to add that for every file trying to click, I get: File Not found error.
[image]

Comment: Check your apache configuration. Specifically the .cgi handling.

Comment: I think at this point it would be easier to install bugzilla from Ubuntu repos instead of trying to build everything from tarballs... maybe purging apache and mysql packages along with their configs before installing bugzilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to tell Apache to associate .cgi extension with Perl. Also, index.cgi should be treated as directory index. Here's [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) (not for faint-hearted)

I would expect the README file I can see on your screenshot contains valuable hints and pointers - have you read it?

**UPDATE:** You're doing it all wrong. :) See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla/62227#62227)

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the README. It states i canchoose between perl and cgi. going over the instruction on [install cgi](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html) still did not help. can't exectue cgi

Comment: Just install it from repositories :) See the link in UPDATE